# Where did libgmp3-dev for Ubuntu 16.10 go?

Tags: apt, package-management, 16.10

On Yakkety:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.10
Release:        16.10
Codename:       yakkety
```

I can't seem to install `libgmp3-dev`:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libgmp3-dev
[sudo] password for exarkun: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package libgmp3-dev is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libgmp3-dev' has no installation candidate
```

[Yet it appears as though I *ought* to be able to](http://packages.ubuntu.com/yakkety/libgmp3-dev).

[And apparently at least one other person can install this package on 16.10](https://github.com/AntonKueltz/fastecdsa/issues/7#issuecomment-294105238).  And as you can see, I'm having trouble installing fastecdsa and the lack of libgmp3-dev seems related.

Here's my `sources.list` (minus comment lines):

```
deb http://mirror.nodesdirect.com/ubuntu/ yakkety-updates main restricted
deb-src http://mirror.nodesdirect.com/ubuntu/ yakkety-updates main restricted

deb http://mirror.nodesdirect.com/ubuntu/ yakkety universe
deb-src http://mirror.nodesdirect.com/ubuntu/ yakkety universe
deb http://mirror.nodesdirect.com/ubuntu/ yakkety-updates universe
deb-src http://mirror.nodesdirect.com/ubuntu/ yakkety-updates universe

deb http://mirror.nodesdirect.com/ubuntu/ yakkety multiverse
deb-src http://mirror.nodesdirect.com/ubuntu/ yakkety multiverse
deb http://mirror.nodesdirect.com/ubuntu/ yakkety-updates multiverse
deb-src http://mirror.nodesdirect.com/ubuntu/ yakkety-updates multiverse

deb http://mirror.nodesdirect.com/ubuntu/ yakkety-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://mirror.nodesdirect.com/ubuntu/ yakkety-backports main restricted universe multiverse


deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ yakkety-security universe multiverse main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ yakkety-security universe multiverse main restricted
```

`mirror.nodesdirect.com` comes from https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors (previously I was using the Princeton Mathematics mirror with the same outcome).

Why can't I install this package?

Comment: `libgmp3-dev` seems to be available : http://packages.ubuntu.com/yakkety/libgmp3-dev ... May be you forgot to run `apt-get update` , to refresh your package list ?  I.e. the install command is `apt-get update && apt install libgmp3-dev`

Comment: Sorry, shoulda said, my package db is up to date (ie, I ran `apt-get update` 20 times trying to figure this out)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your sources.list file, I see that you're missing `main` component of the repository. Add these two lines to the `sources.list` file and then do a package index update using `sudo apt update`

```
deb http://mirror.nodesdirect.com/ubuntu/ yakkety main
deb-src http://mirror.nodesdirect.com/ubuntu/ yakkety main
```

Then install the package as usual

---

It's gone nowhere. Available for yakkety too. http://packages.ubuntu.com/yakkety/libgmp3-dev

Check your software sources if you enabled respective ones.

Comment: I linked to that page.

Comment: @Jean-PaulCalderone Add the content of your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file in the question

Comment: @Jean-PaulCalderone Check the update

Comment: Maybe you're fiddling with it too much or eaten by some ghost :D